# error while trying to route to a new class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

i tested some react coding and wanted to start a project with multiple classes to which i route to from the index.js. But whenever i do that it gives me the error: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'D: etc
Hope you can help me.

here is the standard app.js

```
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  return (   
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is my index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Test from './components/test';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './App';

const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
      <Route exact path='/teams' component={Test}></Route>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)


ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

and here my test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <p>test</p>
    }

}
export default Test
```

Comment: Have you added `react-router-dom` to your project?

Comment: i imported it, but i guess you mean somewhere in the node modules?

Comment: You have to add it to your project, for example by `npm`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Comment: thanks, i just installed it through npm and it compiled now(after i fixed the missing return in test.js). It routes me to the test.js but it doesnt show the "test" output somehow.

Comment: it only shows a blank white page